# Textarea Calculations

Tags: javascript, math, textarea

I'm trying to have three textareas. The first two are addends and the last is the sum. What's supposed to happen is if your math equation is correct, a paragraph will say `true`.

Else, it'll say `false`. However, the paragraph doesn't say anything when I try.
Here's my code:

```
<textarea id="x"></textarea>
<textarea id="y"></textarea>
<textarea id="z"></textarea>
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById('x').innerHTML;
  var y = document.getElementById('y').innerHTML;
  var z = x + y;
  var p = document.getElementById('p');
</script>
<button oclick="if (z = document.getElementById('z').innerHTML) {p.innerHTML = true} else {p.innerHTML = false}">Calculate</button>
<br>
<p id="p"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First attaching the click event to your button from the JS code using `addEventListener` will be better (avoid the inline-events), then put your code inside, you have to use `.value` insted of `innerHTML` to get the value of a textarea.

Note also that you should use double equals `==` when you want to compare two elements, and because we need to perform a math operations we should cast our values to numbers using `Number()` method.

Should be something like :

```js
document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var x = Number( document.getElementById('x').value );
  var y = Number( document.getElementById('y').value );
  var z = x + y;
  var p = document.getElementById('p');

  if (z == document.getElementById('z').value) {
    p.innerText = "true";
  } else {
    p.innerText = "false";
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea id="x"></textarea>
<textarea id="y"></textarea>
<textarea id="z"></textarea>
<button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
<br>
<p id="p"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**first** of all, I suggest you to use input here instead of 
**Second** thing is, I would suggest you to use function when you use 'onclick'

Here's the result:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type='number' placeholder='x: (input number please)' id="x" />
<input type='number' placeholder='y: (input number please)' id="y" />
<input type='number' placeholder='z: (input number please)' id="z" />
<br />
<button onclick="CheckByFormula()">Calculate</button>
<br />
<p>Check result: z=x+y ?</p>
<p id="p"></p>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function CheckByFormula(){
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('x').value);
  var y = parseInt(document.getElementById('y').value);
  var z = x + y;
  //alert('having these params:\n x='+x+' y='+y+' z='+z);
  var p = document.getElementById('p');  
  z1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('z').value);
  alert('z1='+z1+' z='+z);
    if(z1 == z){
        document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = 'true'
    } 
    else {
        document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = 'false';
    }
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/14pm7ypz/2/